# Trigger replication update manually and not automatically in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, replication, transactional-replication

I have set up an Transactional Replication in SQL Server 2012 and it works fine (update after some seconds)
But is it possible to edit my replication to trigger only if i "push a button for" and not automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you setup Transactional Replication and create subscriptions you can synchronize subscriptions:

- **Continuously**
- **On demand**
- **On a schedule**

This is covered in [Synchronize Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151793.aspx).

It sounds like you have configured your subscription to either synchronize continuously or on a schedule.

If you would like to synchronize your subscription on demand, i.e., by pushing a button, you can do this a couple of different ways which are covered in [Synchronize a Push Subscriptio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151169.aspx)n and [Synchronize a Pull Subscription](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151261.aspx):

1. Using SQL Server Management Studio
2. Invoking the replication agent executable
3. Using Replication Management Objects (RMO)

Both of the links above provide descriptions and examples of each approach.  The quickest way to synchronize on demand by pushing a button is via SQL Server Management Studio.  Right-click your subscription you want to synchronize on demand and click **View Synchronization Status**.  Then click **Start**.

Answer (score 0):

If by this you mean to be able to select which changes you want to replicate - no, there is no way I can think of doing this. But if you mean deciding on when the changes will replicate you can change the scheduling of your distribution agent to run on demand.